# How can I access properties from a view to another?

Tags: xcode, swift

Note before anything, I'm pretty much new to coding but I have tried my best on searching for answers on my own, I'm sorry if I ask too silly questions D:

I'm trying to make a setting page where you can turn off sounds/bgm for the whole app, and so far I have managed to link a view to another in code.

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController { 

var ButtonSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("tamborine", ofType: "wav")!)
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var BGMaudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


func playBgMusic(){
    let musicPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Waiting-in-the-Woods", ofType: "mp3")
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: musicPath!)
    BGMaudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: nil)
    BGMaudioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    //-1為循環播放
    BGMaudioPlayer.volume = 1
    BGMaudioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    BGMaudioPlayer.play()


}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ButtonSound, error: nil)

           //Bgm.play()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
      playBgMusic()


    if !BGMaudioPlayer.playing {
        playBgMusic()
    }
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


@IBAction func quitBtn(sender: UIButton) {
 audioPlayer.play()
    exit(0);
}
@IBAction func Start(sender: UIButton) {
   audioPlayer.play()

}

}
```

Setting.Swift

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class Setting: UIViewController {

let mainView = ViewController()

@IBOutlet weak var BGMSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var SoundsSwitch: UISwitch!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func soundsswitch(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !SoundsSwitch.on{
        mainView.BGMaudioPlayer.stop()
    }else{
        mainView.BGMaudioPlayer.play()
    }

    }

}
```

It builds but then it crashes down when I turn the switch off...
Thanks in advance. D:

Comment: what crash message are you getting

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)   I'm not sure if I'm looking at the right place, but I think it's this.

Comment: This is not how you go from one controller to another. You must use a Segue.

Comment: This: `let mainView = ViewController()` ...is almost always going to be wrong.  It creates a new `ViewController` object; it does not return the one you already created.  Even if you did want a new controller, this doesn't use your storyboard/xib definition of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

For sending data between views you can either implement

`override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {`

```
    if (segue.identifier == "Segue Identifier") {

    }
```

**OR**

Use delegate to communicate between views.

You can find a lot about these 2 implementations here on stack overflow.